# trying to setup svn external diff program on mac

Tags: macos, svn, diff, filemerge, opendiff

I'm having problems trying to setup an external diff program for svn on Mac OSX Lion. 
I have both xxdiff and opendiff installed.

I add these lines to ~/.subversion/config:

```
diff-cmd = opendiff
diff3-cmd = opendiff
```

or

```
diff-cmd = /Applications/xxdiff.app/Contents/MacOS/xxdiff
diff3-cmd = /Applications/xxdiff.app/Contents/MacOS/xxdiff
```

But when I invoke svn, I get this error:

```
svn: /Users/tre11/.subversion/config:49: Option expected
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't many diff utilities, aside from the GNU ones of course, that will take the parameters as given by svn (bbdiff is one of the few). You need to wrap the call in a shell script. It's explained [in the subversion docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html).

**Edit**
Based on your comment that the default text diff is still being run, I think there's an error in your .subversion/config file. That's consistent with your error message. The most likely cause is a space at the beginning of the `diff-cmd` line. Yes, subversion's parser freaks out at spaces at the beginning of the line. I put a space at the beginning of my `diff-cmd` line and got the same "Option expected" error.

Comment: I've looked at that but I'm still struggling to get it to work with svn. When I do `svn diff` it still uses the default text diff.

Comment: I figured out what my problem was. I had a space before the diff-cmd line. :P

Comment: Since that's what I suggested was your problem you may want to consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of one I use with MacVIM

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant DIFF => qw(mvim -d -f);

my $parameters = $#ARGV;
my $file1 = $ARGV[$parameters - 1];
my $file2 = $ARGV[$parameters];
my $title1 = $ARGV[$parameters - 4];
my $title2 = $ARGV[$parameters - 2];

$ENV{TITLE} = "$title1  -   $title2";
system DIFF, '-c', 'let &titlestring=$TITLE', $file1, $file2;
```

This is a Perl program (but you have Perl on your Mac, so it's okay).

Basically, you have to know the various parameter positions passed to your program. A quick test shows the following parameters were passed:

1. `-u`  (Unified Diff)
2. `-L`  (In diff, use the following as the title of the left hand file)
3. `bludgen.pl  (revision 63)`  (Left hand title)
4. `-L`  (In diff, use the following as the title of the right hand file)
5. `bludgen.pl  (working copy)`  (Right hand title)
6. `.svn/text-base/bludgen.pl.svn-base`  (Left hand file)
7. `bludgen.pl` (right hand file)

More information [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html).