# VIM - Passing colon-commands list via command-line

Tags: bash, svn, vim, diff, vimdiff

Good day,

I am writing a simple script within my BASHRC file to accommodate something I couldn't quite resolve in a previous question:

[Side-by-side view in Vim of svn-diff for entire directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182024/side-by-side-view-in-vim-of-svn-diff-for-entire-directory)

I basically generate a list of all files which have a "Modified" SVN status. For each of these files, I want to create a side-by-side visual diff, convert it to HTML, then append it to a running HTML file.

eg:

```
MODIFIED_FILES="$(svn status | grep "^M" | cut -c9-)"
for i in ${MODIFIED_FILES}; do
  # Generate a side-by-side diff in vim via VIMDIFF
  # Convert via ToHTML
  # Append the HTML file to a file called "overall_diff.html"
done
```

I can accomplish the vimdiff easily enough by creating a clean copy of the file, and having a copy of the modified file.

`vimdiff` has an issue at first, ie:

```
2 files to edit
Error detected while processing /Users/Owner/.vimrc:
line   45:
E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:>-,trail:.,extends:>,precedes:«
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

So, I am trying to get past this so I don't have to hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> for each file in my list.

Next, I need to have `vimdiff` call the `ToHTML` command, and then issue the command to append the HTML buffer to a running file:

```
:'<,'>w! >>overall_diff.html
```

In short, how do I:

1. Get past this issue with `listchars` when `vimdiff` is called. This issue doesn't occur when I run `vim`, so I don't know why it occurs when I run `vimdiff`.
2. Pass a list of colon-commands to VIM to have it run them at `startup` without requiring a change to my `.vimrc` file.

Comment: Take a look at `vim -c` in the manpages

Comment: It seems like it should work. You'll have to show us what your call to vimdiff with 2 files looks like. Turn on `set -vx` to see shell debugging output? Some other character creeping into your cmd line?  (you probably know this, sorry). If you take the same cmd that is generated by your script and copy/paste to a cmd-line does vimdiff still complain? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I created a separate VIMRC file that gets passed to the `vim` command at run time, via:

```
`vim -d file1 fil2 -u my_special_vimrc_file`

function createVimDiff()
{
   # Create some buffers
   TEMP_FILE="./tmp_file"
   VIM_TEMP="./temp.html"
   REVISION=""
   BUFFER_FILE="./overall_diff.html"
   # Get a list of the files that have changed
   MODIFIED_FILES="$(svn status | grep '^M' | cut -c9-)"
   # Remove buffers
   rm "${BUFFER_FILE}"
   for i in ${MODIFIED_FILES}; do
      # Remove intermediate buffers
      rm "${TEMP_FILE}"
      rm "${VIM_TEMP}"
      # Get the current SVN rev number for the current file
      REVISION="$(svn info ${i} | grep Revision)"
      # Echo the name of the file to the report
      echo "FILE: ${i}" >> "${BUFFER_FILE}"
      # Same with the revision number
      echo "${REVISION}" >> "${BUFFER_FILE}"
      echo "<br>" >> "${BUFFER_FILE}"
      # First print a copy of the unmodified file in a temporary buffer
      svn cat "${i}" > "${TEMP_FILE}"
      # Now print the unmodified file on the left column, and the
      # modified file in the right column, so they appear side-by-side
      vim -d "${TEMP_FILE}" "${i}" -u ~/.vimdiff_rc
      # Write the side-by-side diff to a file
      cat "${VIM_TEMP}" >> "${BUFFER_FILE}"
      echo "<br>" >> "${BUFFER_FILE}"
   done
   # Cleanup temporary buffers
   rm "${TEMP_FILE}"
   rm "${VIM_TEMP}"
}
```

And the following was put into my VIMRC file:

```
" Convert the diff to HTML
autocmd VimEnter * silent TOhtml

" Write output to temporary buffer
autocmd VimEnter * w! ./temp.html

" Quit VIM
autocmd VimEnter * qa!
```